# How to copy the output of pacman-color into a file and to display the output with the colors in the terminal

Tags: arch-linux, io-redirection, pipe, colors, pacman

Originally I used `pacman`, not `pacman-color` and I copied the output into a file and I displayed the output in the terminal with the following command :

```
pacman -Syu | tee file.log
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `pacman-color` detects that the output is sent to a pipe and it deactives the colored output.
So my question is how to force `pacman-color` to display a colored output even if the output is sent to a pipe? As with yaourt :

> yaourt -Syu --color | tee file.log

Or maybe there is a way to do it without using pipe or `tee`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
script -c 'pacman-color -Syu' file.log
```

Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515208/1176000).

Comment: Wow awesome it works !!! I had already read the question you linked but I hadn't understand the power of 'script'.  And with the '-q' option is usefull to only print the command output.